# Django template tags in JavaScript - invalid syntax without quotes, invalid syntax with quotes

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

It is possible you have Javascript read vars from Django template tags like `var spec = "{{ foo }}";`.

However, if foo needs to be a JSON object. it becomes like this:

```
var spec = "{"2": {"guid": 2, "contentBlocks": {"2_1": {"guid": "2_1", "type": "list"}}}}";
```

The preceding and closing quotes make this an invalid JavaScript syntax, however, if I leave them out, it is also an invalid syntax  `var spec = {{ foo }};`

What would be the best way to solve this problem? Either to have `foo` output the complete `<script></script>` block, or to have JavaScript request this object from the server, instead of outputting it via a template tag? ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a JSON object, it doesn't need to be quoted at all. JSON syntax is valid Javascript syntax (although of course the reverse is not necessarily true).

```
var spec = {{ foo }};
```

is perfectly good if `foo` evaluates to a JSON string.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you wanted it to be a string, try single quotes:

```
var spec = '{"2": {"guid": 2, "contentBlocks": {"2_1": {"guid": "2_1", "type": "list"}}}}';
```

If you want it to be a JavaScript object, don't use the quotes at all.

```
var spec = {"2": {"guid": 2, "contentBlocks": {"2_1": {"guid": "2_1", "type": "list"}}}};
```

This is valid syntax.

However, Django will escape the quotes if you don't mark it as safe. So, say that json block is the_json in your template,

```
var spec={{ the_json |safe }}
```

is what you want. Without the safe filter, the quotes would be output as `&quot;`, invalidating the JSON.

Comment: I usually use mark_safe() in the return values, or would you not recommend that?

Comment: Either way works fine, of course - just depends if you'd rather do it in the template or the view.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are perfectly ok if JS is embedded in a template. And if you have a separate .js files that are served statically, then you can expose the nesessary variables in your templates:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var g_foo = {{ foo }};
</script>
```

-- and then in .js use this `g_foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. It turned out to be that Dreamweaver tells me syntax is invalid, but when executing the script it works perfect.